# How to view the full Typescript type when merging types

Tags: typescript

When extending a Typescript type, is there any way to view the entire "merged object"?

```
type FileObj = Express.Multer.File & {
  destination?: string;
  filename?: string;
  lang?: string;
  mimetype?: string;
  originalname: string;
  path: string;
};
```

[image]

I would expect to see BOTH the Multer Filter type mixed with the properties I defined.

Comment: Do you mean seeing all of the props listed? Just start accessing a prop, type `thing.`, and they'll all be shown.

Comment: Yes, like the tooltip. I'm wondering if I need to do something to make both available

Comment: I don't think you can; the language service will show the *name* for a type where available, you only see the props for the other part of the intersection because it doesn't have a name.

Comment: typescript `&`  `|` is not simply object merging, it has it's own complicated rules of type checking